# Java exception thrown when reading input

Tags: java

I am reading a set of integer values in from a .txt file in Java using `Scanner` and `FileReader`.  There is one value per line in the input file. All of the values are read into the `StringBuilder` variable, but for some reason the compiler throws an exception right at the end of reading the input in the while loop and I can't quite figure out why.

```
    Scanner inFile;
    String value = "";
    String arrayString = "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("data.txt"));
        value = inFile.next();
        while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
            sb.append(value);
            value = inFile.next();
        }

        arrayString = sb.toString(); // Not executing
        System.out.println(arrayString); // Not executing
        inFile.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: File not found.");
    } finally {
        // inFile.close();
    }
    System.out.println(arrayString); // Not executing
```

Comment: what type of exception?

Comment: paste exception trace

Comment: The compiler never throws exceptions. Is it a compiler *error* that you get while compiling, or do you get an exception while running the code?

Comment: Instead of printing "Error: File not found." please use e.getMessage().

Comment: Use either `scanner.hasNextLine()` and `scanner.nextLine()` OR `scanner.hasNext()` and `scanner.next()`, but don't mix them. Empty lines can cause issues like the one you're having.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I left the data file as it was but amended the code so that I use scanner.hasNext() and scanner.next(), as suggested. Code works now.

Answer (score 1):

> the compiler throws an exception right at the end of reading the input in the while loop

A compiler does not "throw exceptions". Instead it gives errors/warnings related to issues in your code itself.

Having said this, "at the end of reading the input" implies your file may contain new line characters after the set of integer values. If this is the case then your `Scanner` will throw a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` when calling `value = inFile.next();`.

You can try the following way of reading instead:

```
while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
    value = inFile.nextLine();
    sb.append(value);
}
```

Also try to print the exception message in your `catch` block. A `java.util.NoSuchElementException` does not mean `Error: File not found.`

Answer (score 0):

I created file with integer from 1 to 6 , same code is working fine.
If there is no blank space on last line.
But If I am keeping last line with blank or space , then its going into Exception.
just check, is your last line of data.txt file having blank space?

Comment: Sir@thecbuilder, I don't have 50 reputation to make a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably get a `FileNotFoundException` on  `inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("data.txt"));`

You could also get several exceptions when you are reading a file using a scanner. You are catching an `Exception` so everything will be caught.

Now the lines :

```
arrayString = sb.toString(); // Not executing
System.out.println(arrayString); // Not executing
inFile.close(); // --> Is also not executed. Resource leak here. put it in finally.
```

are outside the `try{}` block, so, they will not get executed.

catch{}`gets executed because you have an exception and`finally{}` gets executed *always*.

So, `System.out.println(arrayString);` is outside of the `try{} , catch{}, finally{}` scope, so it will not get executed.